# Fatal Error on Wordpress: Call to undefined function wp() in wp-blog-header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I updated Wordpress to 4.2 this morning, and now I can't access my Wordpress site, gteam.org.

I've searched the Wordpress help forum, but to no avail.

Thoughts or help:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp() in /home/team1874/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 14

Comment: it sounds like the update failed possibly due to insufficient disk space. Manually updating via FTP should fix this

Comment: Further to this, updating a live site is a bad idea anyway. Always test your planned updates beforehand.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error, problem was my wp-config.php file was somehow empty, just copied the example wp-config and added my configuration and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem this morning when trying to install wordpress v4.9.4 . The most likely reason is that the file which declared function wp() is somehow damaged. I solved it reload a new package  and installed.

references: 
*https://wordpress.org/support/topic-tag/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-wp/*

Comment: The wordpress linke you've shared is no longer available. It is stackoverflow best practices to provide some text solution with the link in case this happens.